# INDIRECT FUNCTION doesn't work in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to sum a discontinuous range with SUM, COUNTIF and INDIRECT formulas. It works well in Excel, but when I upload my file in Google Drive and open it, the sum is different.

This is my formula. When I mark with X the cells D3, F3 or H3, I get the sum.

> =SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"D3","F3","H3"},TRUE),"X"))

The same formula in Google Sheets only get the sum of D3, if I modify F3 or H3, the result doesn't change

Is there a way that you can function this formula in Google Sheets or get the sum of discontinuous cells?

Thank you!

Comment: If you reference to cells on the same sheet I recommend avoiding `INDIRECT` at all. Instead you could use `INDEX` like for instance: `INDEX(A:H,3,{4,6,8})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In google sheets you can join the cells into a single array using curly brackets - you don't need the indirect:

```
=countif({D3,F3,H3},"X")
```

[image]

Having said this, GS isn't quite as flexible as Excel with indirect. If you had two different sized ranges like A1:B2 and C1:E3 and tried to combine them, GS would give a 'mismatched row size' error. You could get round it by flattening them like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(countif({flatten(A1:B2);flatten(C1:E3)},"X"))
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!