# Indirect function not selecting for multiple sheets in google sheets but works in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

We are trying to keep track of stocks across multiple freezers. I have a sheet per freezer rack and want to know the number of a specific item in those shelves. The formula I have written works well in excel but not in google sheets.

Here is my formula:

=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&'List of sheets '!A2:A8&"'!A1:AZ1000"), "ATP001", INDIRECT("'"&'List of sheets '!A2:A8&"'!A1:AZ1000"), "P3", INDIRECT("'"&'List of sheets '!A2:A8&"'!A1:AZ1000"), "<>iNPC"))

This should select across 7 sheets any item (cell) that contains the terms ATP001, P3 and iNPC.

The 7 sheets are listed in another sheet called List of sheets and in cells A2-A8. The formula output is only counting the first sheet in cell A2.

Annoyingly it works great in excel but not in google sheets which as a team we share.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70052959/12634230

Comment: First question: why do you think Excel is the same as Googlesheets?

Comment: To do this you have to build an array using the REDUCE function. But unless I'm missing something your COUNTIFS formula is wrong anyway... you are providing the same range to all the _range_ arguments, so it is impossible for all the conditions to be met at the same time.

Comment: @z''
thanks for your advice about the REDUCE function, how would that work? The COUNTIFS part of the formula does appear to work as all conditions must appear in the same cell. Unfortunately it isn't my spreadsheet otherwise I would split the conditions into seperate columns but my department requires it in this format

Comment: @T_J_Neuro, it's better to show you. Can you share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result? You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)